# sharing data between other users/devices

Tags: android, database, backend, android-sharing

I am creating an Android game where users need to share data with anonymous users on a different device and location should not matter. I am assuming I need to create a server to store that information and users request data when needed from that server. Does Android have any API like sharedPreferences that allows an easy way to save data for any user to see? If not then how would I create and use a server for android.

I do not have much experience dealing with servers or sharing data over the network, so any links or explanations would be great!

Comment: Is the data accessable for everyone or do the users share it with specific persons?

Comment: It is accessible to everyone.  The user cannot share with one specific person  the data is shared with everyone when they are playing the game

Comment: Than you have to setup a server.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server with PHP and MYSQL support. PHP helps you to save data into the MYSQL database and you could use queries to get specific data from the database. From android you need to make requests to your server and the server should return the data in JSON format, which is easier to process.

Free web hosting:

[Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/), [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/), etc..

More details:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: Or just use Firebase, which is free and doesn't require learning PHP or SQL

Comment: @cricket_007 Firebase no longer free...any other ideas on how to share an app's data between users for no cost?

Comment: @AJW It is free up to a limit... https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: So if the dev builds an app that becomes wildly successful (say 1 million users) it seems from the pricing plan that Firebase could become a very costly platform for rather basic functionality (sharing simple data between users).  I am looking for alternatives to keep costs low...